# How to make a *TODO* buffer, and it is open every time I conjure emacs?

Tags: emacs

I want to make *TODO* list buffer (text mode or whatever other mode) that is open whenever I start the emacs. How can I do that?

Comment: Just as a note, AquaMacs Emacs has a buffer exactly like this (except the buffer is not called "TODO").

Comment: pascal, which buffer in aquamacs are you referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding:

```
(pop-to-buffer "*TODO*")
```

to your .emacs.  The buffer isn't linked to a file, for that you could add:

```
(find-file "~/TODO")
```

Though, for TODO lists, you might want to check out [org-mode](http://orgmode.org/).  It's distributed with Emacs 22.1, and I'd follow the link to check it out.  I know people that switched to Emacs just to get access to org-mode.

Comment: I strongly second the suggestion of checking out org-mode for TODO handling, and once you're used to it, you might also want to check out a sub-feature of org-mode called 'capture mode' which allows you to quickly enter TODO items (or other templated things) which are collected into a personal TODO file - although capture mode is a feature of the development version of org mode and won't be included by default just yet (it replaces a very very similar feature called remember mode though that IS in the bundled org-mode of emacs 23)

Answer (score 2):

What you want is [Org Mode](http://orgmode.org/).  It's included in Emacs these days.